# What does LoaderManager do?

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I am trying to understand what does `LoaderManager` do. Can anyone share an example with it? Must I use them when I create a cursor? If not how should I use? A simple example is very appreciated.

Comment: There is a good article on `Loaders` in [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html). There are two sample there: [LoaderCursor](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderCursor.html) and [LoaderThrottle](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderThrottle.html).

Comment: [**Understanding the `LoaderManager` (part 2)**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) is a great post to learn from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply stated, the `LoaderManager` is responsible for managing one or more `Loader`s associated with an `Activity` or `Fragment`. Each `Activity` and each `Fragment` has exactly one `LoaderManager` instance that is in charge of starting, stopping, retaining, restarting, and destroying its `Loader`s.

There is a pretty extensive and in-depth blog post on the `LoaderManager`... check it out here:

#### [**Understanding the LoaderManager (part 2)**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/why-you-should-use-loadermanager.html)

Answer (score 1):

**In simple words:**

`LoaderManager` load the data in background and also look for the changes in it. It provides a simple Api like structure that we don't need to look and observer the data manually.

**Examples:**

In `<android-sdk>\samples` folder search for `LoaderCursor.java` and `LoaderThrottle.java` this are the to example using [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) class

Just in case if some one is looking for an example of `LoaderManager` with the custom `AsyncTaskLoader` look [here](https://github.com/nixit28/LoaderExample).

Comment: I would stay away from using `Loader`s to perform web requests. A better solution would be to have a service periodically request data from the server and then insert it into a `ContentProvider`, then using a `CursorLoader` to query the data. I believe this is a better solution because (1) it is easy to implement an "offline-mode" for your app if you have modeled things this way, and (2) `Loader`s are usually specific to a single `Activity` or `Fragment`, so it would be difficult to extend this design if you wished to receive background notifications outside of the `Activity`, for example.

Comment: indeed you are correct but, as far as I am concerned Loader looks the best available option for my application @ this point, why because the data in to which I am querying is the the Stock Market Data and I don't think it is good Idea to make it offline. caching of data will be faster but it is not fitting to my mind, how?

Comment: @NikitPatel I'm not sure what kind of app you are writing, but I always get annoyed when apps don't work simply because there is no internet connection. It's also little more battery intensive using a `Loader` since you have to load data *every single time* you create the `Activity`.